# How to fix google play console unsupported devices(OpenGL ES and framework version)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I uploaded my unity android game in Google Play Console but got many unsupported devices. Reasons for devices being unsupported are

1. Doesn't support required OpenGL ES version: 3.0
2. Doesn't support framework version: 22 and onwards

In Project Settings> Other Settings I have set Graphics APIs Vulkan, OpenGLES3 and OpenGLE2 in that order and

Minimum API Level: Android 4.4 'KitKat' (API level 19)

Target API Level: Automatic (highest installed)

I tried setting Auto Graphics API and changing the order of the APIs in list but still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is normal that there are a few unsupported cell phone models in the Playstore. There are such a large number of devices that its not possible to modify your app for all of them.

#### 1

So I have also published a game from Unity to the playstore.
I haven't played around with the Graphics API at all. I set it to Automatic (the default values ​​are DirectX 3.0, DirectX 2.0)
and it works fine.
In your case, Vulkan might get used to build and google does not like it.

### 2

Probably the fix from number 1 will fix this problem, but to really help, we need more informations.

Comment: Already tried these but didn't work. I'm testing with Huawei P8 Lite(model hwALE-H)